# JSP Error: contains invalid expression. Failed to parse the expression

Tags: jsp, tomcat7

I am trying to debug an old jsp site and so I installed tomcat 7 and Netbeans IDE 7.2.1 on my local machine running windows 7 and got everything setup. But when I run it, I am getting an error:

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
>   org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /pages/caselisting.jsp (line: 133, column: 35) "${case.patientmaxdate}" contains invalid expression(s): javax.el.ELException: Failed to parse the expression [${case.patientmaxdate}]

The code at that line is:

```
<td><c:out default="&nbsp;" escapeXml="false" value="${case.patientmaxdate}"/></td>
```

I am very new to jsp and am trying to make some changes to this old site. I did some research and read that Tomcat 7 made some changes for this error. I would appreciate if somebody can guide me in the right direction.

Thanks.

The complete stack trace:

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
>   org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /pages/caselisting.jsp (line: 133,
>   column: 35) "${case.patientmaxdate}" contains invalid expression(s):
>   javax.el.ELException: Failed to parse the expression
>   [${case.patientmaxdate}]  at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:42)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:408)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:199)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.checkXmlAttributes(Validator.java:1223)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.visit(Validator.java:875)
>     at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1539)
>     at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2376)  at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2428)     at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.visit(Validator.java:894)
>     at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1539)
>     at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2376)  at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2428)     at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2434)     at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:475)    at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2376)   at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator.validateExDirectives(Validator.java:1795)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:217)
>     at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:373)   at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)    at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)    at
>   org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:646)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
>     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(RequestProcessor.java:1056)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.doForward(TilesRequestProcessor.java:261)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(RequestProcessor.java:388)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(TilesRequestProcessor.java:316)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:231)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1164)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:397)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at filter.SecureFilter.doFilter(SecureFilter.java:38)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1822)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

The complete code surrounding the error line is:

```
 <c:forEach items="${caselist}" var="case">
   <tr onMouseOver="this.bgColor='#EEEEEE';" onMouseOut="this.bgColor='';">
    <td><c:out default="&nbsp;" escapeXml="false" value="${case.patientmaxdate}"/></td>
```

Here caselist is an array list.

Comment: Post the compete stack trace. Is 'case' a bean in scope? Does it have a property named 'patientmaxage'? Spelt like that, with no uppercase?

Comment: @EJP I have made the required edit to the question and case being an item of caselist and has a property called 'patientmaxdate'.

Comment: also, the code works fine on an older version of tomcat (5), but now on 7.

Comment: May we see the class definition (or at list it's outline) for the item "case" ?

Answer (score 47):

Not sure whether you ended up solving this one, but having just had a similar problem and solving it, I thought I'd chip in.

The expression parser in Tomcat 7 is apparently less permissive than it was in previous versions. It doesn't like attribute names in EL expressions that clash with reserved keywords in Java.

In your example, the parser might be complaining that you are using the variable name 'case' in your forEach loop. The name 'case' is obviously a reserved Java keyword.

You should change the variable name to something that isn't reserved (perhaps 'aCase'):

```
<c:forEach items="${caselist}" var="aCase">
   <tr onMouseOver="this.bgColor='#EEEEEE';" onMouseOut="this.bgColor='';">
    <td><c:out default="&nbsp;" escapeXml="false" value="${aCase.patientmaxdate}"/>
```

Alternatively, there is a system property that you can set that will make Tomcat 7 more permissive:

```
-Dorg.apache.el.parser.SKIP_IDENTIFIER_CHECK=true
```

You'll need to add that to the end of the list of properties in the Java Options box in the Tomcat 7 properties window (run Tomcat7w.exe).

[image]

That will then apply to all pages in all apps you have running in Tomcat 7.

Comment: In Eclipse you have to add the line org.apache.el.parser.SKIP_IDENTIFIER_CHECK=true
to catalina.properties file inside Servers folder in Package Explorer. Otherwise, configs would not take effect.

Comment: mvn jetty:run -Dorg.apache.el.parser.SKIP_IDENTIFIER_CHECK=true works!!

Comment: Thanks for chipping in! `-Dorg.apache.el.parser.SKIP_IDENTIFIER_CHECK=true` did the trick.

Comment: Was using indeed the keyword 'case', changed the var="... in the forEach. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much! it works well also with tomcat 8.5

Answer (score 3):

The Java keywords (like `case`, `instanceof`, `if`, `while`, `class`, `return`, `static`, etc.) cannot be used as variable/function names in EL. Prefer using different names, for example:

```
<c:forEach items="${caselist}" var="cs">
   <tr onMouseOver="this.bgColor='#EEEEEE';" onMouseOut="this.bgColor='';">
    <td><c:out default="&nbsp;" escapeXml="false" value="${cs.patientmaxdate}"/></td>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, caused by our extensive use of this pattern:

    `<c:if test="${actionVar.class.name == 'MyClass'}">
      <c:import url="${actionVar.cellRender}" /></c:if>`

Problem fixed by adding:

    `org.apache.el.parser.SKIP_IDENTIFIER_CHECK=true`

to `/etc/tomcat7/catalina.properties`

as suggested by @will-keeling

Answer (score 2):

Tomcat 7 does not include the JSTL by default, you must add that separately in order to use EL expressions.  If line 133 is the first occurrence of using an EL expression on the page, then you should verify the JSTL library is included within $CATALINA_HOME/lib or within your WEB-INF/lib directory.

Comment: The jstl library is already added and there are other EL expression which work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

1: **don't forget the closing "}"**.

Seems simple, but I've done this a few times when the expressions get a bit complex.

2: **Set attribute silently fails when you use ".":**

```
<% pageContext.setAttribute("my_namespace.MY_VAR", MY_VAR); %>
${my_namespace.MY_VAR}
```

The attribute is set as a single string.
But split when parsed. {$my_namesapce.MY_VAR}
Assumes my_namespace is a map with key "MY_VAR" or
an object with property "MY_VAR"